# RSS reader with adblock

Tags: software-recommendation, rss, google, adblock

Is there any RSS reader with a built-in adblock or a plugin to an RSS reader?

I would also be preferable if it had Google Reader integration.

Answer (score 2):

I've added this rule to the end of `/Applications/Reeder.app/Contents/Resources/article.css`:

```
iframe[src*="feedads"],
iframe[src*="doubleclick"],
iframe[src*="plusone.google"],
a[href*=".ads."],
a[href*="feedads"],
a[href*="feedburner"],
a[href*="doubleclick"],
a[href*="//ads."],
a[href*="api.tweetmeme"],
a[href*="delicious.com/post?"],
a[href*="digg.com/submit?"],
a[href*="google.com/bookmarks/mark?"],
a[href*="posterous.com/share?"],
a[href*="tumblr.com/share?"],
a[href*="linkedin.com/shareArticle?"],
a[href*="facebook.com/share.php?"],
a[href*="http://twitter.com/home?"],
a[href*="addtoany.com/share_save"],
a[href*="twitter.com/share?"],
a[href*="pheedcontent.com/"],
a[href*="feeds.wordpress.com/"],
img[src*=".ads."],
img[src*="//ads."],
img[src*="doubleclick"],
img[src*="feedads"],
img[src*="feedburner"],
img[src*="share-buttons"],
img[src*="pheedo.com/"] {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Most of the selectors were taken from a [CSS file](http://inessential.com/2011/11/21/netnewswire_style_sheet_ballard) posted by the original developer of NetNewsWire.

You could also block [domains that serve ads](http://someonewhocares.org/hosts/) in /etc/hosts.

Comment: Does this works when viewing the full article or just the preview?

Comment: It doesn't affect the combined view that shows articles inline or the built in browser. (But at least I've never needed to use either of them.)

Comment: I need it to work with the built in browser

Comment: Here's the path to the mentioned css file: /Applications/Reeder.app/Contents/Resources/article.css. Just add to the end.

Comment: For a more thorough list of elements to hide, see the "General element hiding rules" section in EasyList's ad block rules: https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/easylist.txt